# "Error Unclassifiable statement" on Linux

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

Compile *.for* format file using gfortran in my Linux cluster.

By typing  `gfortran -O2 calpuff.for -o calpuff.exe`, there happened to be **one error**:

> *Unclassifiable statement*

Error

```
 In file calutils.for:2912
 Included at calpuff.for:2115
   cdeflt=ctext      
 Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

Corresponing *calutil.for* shows like:

```
c ----------------------------------------
c
      character*132 ctext,cdeflt
c
c --- Microsoft variables
c *** integer*2 iarg,istat
c
c --- HP declaration
c *** external getarg
c *** external iargc
c
c --- The following is for any system without a command line routine
c --- and is also used as a default
       cdeflt=ctext   ## Line 2912
c
c ---------------------------------------- 
c ----------------
## Another subroutine.
c --- Sun compiler
c ----------------
     numargs=IARGC()
     if(numargs.ge.1)then
     call GETARG(1,ctext)
     endif   



### Add another subroutine which are the only code related to `cdeflt`
c --- If no command line arguments, use default
  if(ctext(1:1).eq.' ')ctext=cdeflt   # Line 2954

  return
  end
```

#### Update

Thanks for @Alexander Vogt's remind, the code below is *calpuff.for*.

```
c----------------------------------------------------------------------
c --- BRING IN SUBROUTINES for MCHEM=6,7 OPTIONS (API)
      include 'api_chem.for'
      include 'isorropia.for'
c --- BRING IN CALPUFF SYSTEM UTILITY SUBROUTINES
      include 'calutils.for'   ###　This is line 2115
      include 'coordlib.for'
c----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What's wrong with `cdeflt=ctext`? Can someone give some advice?

Comment: OK. I'll upload it right now!

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I add some more code after line 2912 of `calutil.for`. What's more, I upload my whole file into [Code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7FE0kxAL8kQcVpzNnFlYV9vMFU).

Comment: More background story: The _Code_ file can be compiled into `calpuff.exe` for air quality modeling. I had tried to modify some subroutines in `calutil.for` to change the compiler. The original one was `Lahel compiler` for Windows. I want to change it into `gfortran`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual error occurs in the lines afterwards:

```
c ----------------
c --- Sun compiler
c ----------------
     numargs=IARGC()
     if(numargs.ge.1)then
     call GETARG(1,ctext)
     endif
```

You just have five blanks in there, (at least) six are required. It should read

```
c ----------------
c --- Sun compiler
c ----------------
      numargs=IARGC()
      if(numargs.ge.1)then
        call GETARG(1,ctext)
      endif
```

In fixed form Fortran, the first six columns have a special meaning and may not be used for code.

Unfortunately, this (again) makes your question a duplicate of a multitude of others on SO.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I have fixed that problem before this error happened(Forget to change the Google Docs).That time, I had 5 errors

Comment: Then please show the current version.

Comment: Thanks! I uploaded it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7FE0kxAL8kQOGZzMGw2MHZLTHM)

Comment: I don't have a google account and I won't get one.

Comment: Your realize that this is just **five** blanks in your code instead of six?

Comment: You mean this? [figure](http://i12.tietuku.cn/62b8677cc97bfcf8.png)

Comment: Thanks again! I'll check it.

Comment: After you advice, I have figured this error out! But It happened to be another error `calpuff.for: In function ‘r1mach’:
calpuff.for:58522: fatal error: gfc_todo: Not Implemented: Initialization of overlapping variables`. (〒︿〒)

Comment: Please put that into a new question, that issue is not related to this one.

Comment: All right! That's very kind of you to help me so much.